# Не стихаемые, не стихающие

Tags: прилагательные

Знатоки, здравствуйте, подскажите, как правильно если речь идёт о голосах?

Не стихаемые или не стихающие, или и вовсе слитно?

Answer (score 3):

***Не()стихающие голоса***.

Слова *стихаемый* не существует в принципе, потому что глагол *стихать* непереходный, а страдательные причастия образуются только от переходных глаголов. Стихнуть можно самому, а стихнуть кого-то — нет.

А что до слитного или раздельного написания, то всё зависит от контекста.

Раздельно (**не стихающие**) если:

1. Есть зависимые слова (кроме наречий меры и степени): *Ни на минуту не стихающие голоса.*
2. Есть противопоставление: *Не стихающие, а становящиеся громче голоса*.

Слитно  (**нестихающие**):

1. Нет зависимых слов: *Нестихающие голоса*.
2. Есть зависимые слова в виде наречий меры и степени: *Совсем нестихающие голоса*.